# UTL_FILE FAILS WITH ORA-29283: INVALID FILE OPERATION FROM JDBC APPLICATION/WORKS FINE FROM SQL*PLUS

Tags: oracle, plsql

We get the below error while writing file on OS with utl_file package from our application in our PROD environment. The application (which is hosted on IBM WAS) connects to database via JDBC which in turn use the `sys.utl` file package to write the files on OS.

```
ORA-29283: invalid file operation 
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 536 
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
```

The same thing works fine in UAT which has the same setup as PROD

The same operation works on backend from the sql prompt or the batch jobs running. We already checked the below

1. UTL_FILE is working with backend call on the database server.
2. Server User/Group Privileges check between PROD & UAT which is in sync.
3. LDAP User/Group Privileges check between PROD & UAT which is in sync.
4. Directory level permission check between UAT & PROD server, which are identical.
5. Database User Permission & Privileges.

It gives the same error with 777 privileges.

Comment: The application from prod writes in same directry as ur sqlplus do? _Select * from all_Directories;_ this query could list you the oracle directory name and corresponding actual path in OS.

Comment: Yes it writes in the same directory, please note the directory we are trying to use is driven by a parameter table in the application

Comment: When calling UTL_FILE.FOPEN are you specifying a directory object or a path to the directory (e.g. "/dir1/dir2/dir3")? If a directory object, what permissions are granted to the users in question in both environments?

Comment: We are specifying path & currently have given 777 to this path

Comment: If you're using the path directly that path must be specified in the UTL_FILE_DIR parameter in the [startup parameter file](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams003.htm#i1124407). This parameter can't be changed at runtime - it's only read (AFAIK) at startup. You might try doing a `SELECT * FROM SYS.V$PARAMETER` or `SELECT * FROM V$SYSTEM_PARAMETER` and see what that tells you. You'd really be better off using a DIRECTORY object, but perhaps your site frowns on this. Share and enjoy.

Comment: Thanks Bob - we do have the correct utl_file_parameter set & wierd thing is the same code works fine when invoked from sqlplus but when the code is invoked via JDBC from WAS Application it gives us ORA-29283

Comment: What do you have when you call `select value from v$parameter where name='utl_file_dir';` ?